# ClassCastException google spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, spreadsheet, feed, worksheet

when I run my code have this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gdata.data.TextContent cannot be cast to com.google.gdata.data.OutOfLineContent

this is the row code error : `URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();`

I'm trying to **retrieving a list-based feed** but have this error!!!

Help me. please!!!

my class is:

```
package it.unical.mat.google_data;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.batch.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

  public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
       public static void main(String[] args)
                       throws AuthenticationException,    MalformedURLException, IOException,           ServiceException{

 SpreadsheetService service =
         new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

 // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

 // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
 URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
         "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/api-key-here/public/full");

 // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
 SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
         SpreadsheetFeed.class);
 List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

 if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
     // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
 }

 // TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
 // app's needs.
 SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
 System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

 // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
 // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
 // app's needs.
 WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
         spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
 List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
 WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

 // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
 URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
 ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

 // Iterate through each row, printing its cell values.
 for (ListEntry row : listFeed.getEntries()) {
     // Print the first column's cell value
     System.out.print(row.getTitle().getPlainText() + "\t");
     // Iterate over the remaining columns, and print each cell value
     for (String tag : row.getCustomElements().getTags()) {
         System.out.print(row.getCustomElements().getValue(tag) + "\t");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }



 System.out.println("ok!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL hast to be:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/abc/public/full

... according to this website:

http://www.solutionoferror.com/java/outoflinecontent-exception-in-java-google-gdata-spreadsheet-library-169798.asp

Hope this helps! Btw: next time you should remove your API key from your question ;)

Edit: for me the URL https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full returns a good result, but you got to login using the SpreadsheetService first:

```
service.setUserCredentials("user", "pwd");
```

Comment: If I use your URL tipe HAVE THIS ERROR: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
VALUE di visibilità sconosciuto. WHY?

Comment: Have you replaced the "abc" with your key?